# How are logic gates written at their most basic level?

Tags: c, assembly, if-statement, logic

In C, like many other languages, there is the `if` statement. You can use that logic when writing other languages, like C++ or Ruby. However, how does the lowest-level `if` statement work?

How do conditionals function at their lowest level? I don't understand how it can be defined non-recursively.

Comment: You probably want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture

Comment: Read http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Architecture-Fifth-Quantitative-Approach/dp/012383872X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the lowest level, they're implemented in physical hardware. They're not defined in terms of something else, they're actually physically implemented.

Comment: How is that decision made, though? Say a value of `1` is produced. Then what?

Comment: Oversimplifying, there is an actual piece of hardware that the `1` is wired to that stores one address in the program counter register if it gets a `1` wired to it and something else if it gets a `0` wired to it. That `1` actually operates a physical switch that determines what instruction gets executed next.

Comment: Whoa. Awesome! Did not know this.

Comment: You can actually see these switches on the [4004 schematic](http://www.4004.com/assets/redrawn-4004-schematics-2006-11-12.pdf) on the top left of page 2 where the label "ADDRESS MEMORY CONTROL" is. `CONDITION_F/F`, just down and to the right of there, and the circuitry below it, computes that `1`. The 4004 was the first CPU.

Answer (score 3):

You can always look at the generated assembly, but it's usually implemented as a branch or a jump instruction.

```
    if ( x == y )
001E149C  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
001E149F  cmp         eax,dword ptr [y]  
001E14A2  jne         wmain+3Ah (1E14AAh)  
        return 0;
001E14A4  xor         eax,eax  
001E14A6  jmp         wmain+3Fh (1E14AFh)  
    else
001E14A8  jmp         wmain+3Fh (1E14AFh)  
        return 1;
001E14AA  mov         eax,1
```

The if is basically the `jne` (jump not equal) instruction. If the two values (`x` and `y`) aren't equal, it jumps to `else`, otherwise it continues execution and jumps out of the `if`.

Comment: Well, how does it compare? That's what I don't get.

Comment: The processor hardware interprets the `cmp` machine instruction by comparing (usually using the substract circuitery) two numbers and setting some flags according to the result. The `jne` machine instruction jumps if not-equal (i.e. if the flags says the previous `cmp` tested two not-equal words).

Comment: Okay, hit me with hardware, I guess. How does the hardware conditionally check flags?

Comment: Equivalence circuit... See [this article](http://library.thinkquest.org/12666/switches.html) from *A common logic circuit frequently needed in CPUs is the equivalence circuit...*

Comment: @tekknolagi Questions about internal circuits inside a CPU are better asked at http://electronics.stackexchange.com, they are rather off-topic on SO.